# Show $R_{10} $ is isomorphic to $C_4 $

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Determine the Residue group $ R_{10} $ whose binary operation is $\times \  mod \ 10$. Show that:

1. $ R_{10} $ has only one element of order 2
2. $ R_{10} \cong C_4 $

I found that the group $ R_{10} = \{1,3,7,9\} $  trivially.
For no.1 I simply determined the order of each element and showed that the only element of order 2 is 9.

For no.2 I constructed Cayley table for $ C_4 $ and for $R_{10} $ . By observation I constructed a function $\psi C_4 \to R_{10} $ as follows: 
$$e \mapsto 1 \\
g \mapsto 3 \\
g^2 \mapsto 9 \\
g^3 \mapsto 7 $$

This function is clearly a bijection as every element is mapped to a unique element and the function is well-defined.

What is the easiest way to show that this is an homomorphism? I thought of taking any 2 elements $a,b \in C_4 $ and showing that $$\psi (ab)=\psi(a) \psi(b)$$ but this would leave me with $4C2=12$ combinations to consider.

Nevertheless is there an easier way to show that $C_4 \cong R_{10} $ althogether?

Comment: Did you mean $R_{10}=\{1,3,\color{red}9,7\}$?  Anyway, I think it's sufficient to show you have mapped a generator $(g)$ to a generator $(3)$

Comment: Yes, fixed it! So I simply show that $R_{10} = <3>_{3^4 = e} $?

Comment: Yes, you have shown that $R_{10}$ (more standard notations are $\mathbb{Z}_{10}^\times$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{10}^*$ or $U(10)$) have 4 elements and it is cyclic, so $R_{10}\cong C_4$.

Comment: Anyway, also what you did is fine, namely to have realized that under that map the two Cayley tabels are the same (you could take this equality as *definition* of isomorphic groups, and rebuild from this the "operation preserving" property of morphisms, namely yours $\psi(ab)=\psi(a)\psi(b)$!).